# Rewrite URL of a project in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 projects like this www.domain.com/pageSite1 and domain.com/site2/pageSite2 and a structure like this :

```
site1
-htaccess
-content (of site1)
-site2 
--htaccess
--content (of site2)
```

My htaccess from site2 is currently like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_]+)$ content/$1.php [L]
```

But for local dev, urls of site2 points to the root, so I would like to set the site2 folder as "root folder" just for site2 without changing the urls one by one.

I tried to add a RewriteBase /site2 in the site2 htaccess and other tricks but without success.

Thanks for your help !

ps: I don't have access to the httpd.conf, so the alias aren't available

Comment: Are the hostnames different between site1 and site2?

Comment: Nop, this is the same hostname for both and I can't create a subdomain.

Comment: If it's the same, then how are you supposed to tell if a request is meant for site1 or meant for site2?

Comment: Like this www.domain.com/pageSite1 & www.domain.com/site2/pageSite2

Comment: But aren't you trying to access site2 from the root folder?

Comment: I explained it like crap, my links to pages in site2 are like <a href="/randompage"> and I want them to stay like this, but currently it points of course on the root folder and I would like them to points in the subfolder if it's possible. Hope you get the idea :P

Comment: Yeah but as far the mod_rewrite rules go, how does it know that `/randompage` is supposed to route to the content of site1 or the content of site2?

Comment: I thought it would be possible to do it through the htaccess, I finally found a way to create a subdomain so I could let the links how they are. Thanks for your interest